# How to fill color using mplfinance?

Tags: python, plot, mplfinance

I plotted the candlestick chart for the stock price along with some indicators using the mplfinance package. I bought and sold the stock at different prices for many times. Sometimes I win and somethimes I lose. I want to fill the region where I win with green color and the regin where I lose with red color on the main plot. How can I do it?

For instance, how to fill the region between 2022-04-07 and 2022-04-21 with red and the region between 2022-04-27 and 2022-05-10 with green?
[image]

```
import mplfinance as mpf

kwargs = dict(
type='candle', 
mav=(5,10,30), 
volume=True, 
title='%s'%(stock_df.iloc[0,0]),    
ylabel='Price', 
ylabel_lower='Volume', 
#figratio=(1200/72,480/60), 
figscale=3,
datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d',
xrotation=0
)

add_plot = [
mpf.make_addplot(rsi.tail(60),panel=2,ylabel='RSI'),
mpf.make_addplot(slowk.tail(60),panel=3,color='darkslateblue',ylabel='KDJ'),
mpf.make_addplot(slowd.tail(60),panel=3,color='limegreen'),
mpf.make_addplot(slowj.tail(60),panel=3,color='orangered')
]

mpf.plot(
        stock_df.tail(60),  # the stock price 
        **kwargs,
        addplot=add_plot,
        style='yahoo'
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use kwarg `fill_between` when calling `mpf.plot()` or when calling `mpf.make_addplot()`.  Both methods accept `fill_between`.

Do whichever is more convenient.  The difference is that, when passing a `dict` for you `fill_between` value, `mpf.plot()` will accept `panel` as one of the keys in the dict (to place the fill_between on a particular panel), whereas, since `mpf.make_addplot()` has its own `panel` kwarg, there is no need to include it in the `fill_between` dict.

To accomplish what *you* want, coloring only between particular dates, you must pass, a `where` value within the `fill_between` dict.  This `where` value must be a boolean list, equal in length to your dataframe, where `True` indicates that color should be placed at that point, and `False` indicates no color.

For specific examples, see the [**`fill_between` tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/fill_between.ipynb) in the mplfinance documentation.

Note: kwarg `fill_between` [was recently enhanced with version 0.12.9b0](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/releases/tag/v0.12.9b0), adding support for `make_addplot` and allowing a `list` of `fill_between` dicts to be passed.  Make sure you have the latest version of mplfinance: `pip install --upgrade mplfinance`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance! I finally managed to do it.